# How do I give the tasktracker/mapred user within hadoop permissions to modify files and execute processes?

Tags: permissions, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I'm running hadoop and within a mapper process I'm executing some process and creating/editing files.  Unfortunately I'm getting some permissions errors for mapred such as:

```
org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ExitCodeException: cp: cannot create directory
```

Anyone know where to set the permissions for the tasktracker or mapred user to be able to modify files and execute processes?

Also if there's a better way to do this please do let me know.

Comment: Are you creating the files in local file system or in HDFS?

Comment: @Raze2dust - in the local file system

Comment: Can you post some code, a few lines around the exception line? By which username does the tasktracker run? Usually it is the same user by which you run the start-all.sh script. Ensure that that user has write permission on this folder on all the datanodes

Comment: @Raze2dust the username is "mapred", let me reproduce a few more lines around the exception

Comment: ideally I'd like to just give "mapred" root permissions (unfortunately sudo doesn't work via java process)